# How to copy a column containing formulae and values to an Excel ListObject table?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have an Excel table (ListObject) with a calculated column, however, some of the formulas are overwritten with values.

I am trying to read all the rows into an array, make some changes (including adding new lines), and put the modified data back into the table.

My problem is that when I do that, any overwritten values in the calculated column are lost as they are replaced with the original formula.

How can I prevent that behaviour, while still having the formula populated into the newly added rows?

Please note that this is a very simplified example. In reality, there are many semi-calculated columns and I do not want to have to re-write the formula of each one in the code if I can avoid it.

My current simplified code below:

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Tbl")

''copy current tbl into array
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Tbl.DataBodyRange.Formula

''make changes to the array

''copy back from array to tbl
Tbl.DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)) = Arr
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you will have to modify those values that "overwrite" the calculated formula directly on the worksheet. eg. `Tbl.DataBodyRange(5, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "newValue"`

Comment: Nope. That just isn't going to be viable... there are over 10,000 rows and 20 odd columns. It already runs too slowly. Looping through every cell to check if it is a formula or not and then write each one that isn't, individually to the worksheet will take way too long.

Comment: You can save some time by checking in the array to see if it starts with an equal sign. Or you could convert the formulas to ranges and then back again. or maybe someone else will come up with a better answer.

Comment: It's not the checking if they are formulas that will take the time, it is having to write them to the sheet individually. I think I have a solution and will post an answer, although it is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have managed it, although it seems an awful lot of work around for something that should be fairly simple.

During my testing, I have found that the values only get overwritten if we replace all the rows of the table at once (don't ask me why).

So, my solution is to copy the array to the table in two parts.

This sounds simple, but unfortunately, VBA does not make working with arrays particularly easy.

To make it easier, I have included a helper function:

The 'Shift' function moves all the rows in the array "up" by 1.

```
    Function Shift(aRy As Variant)

    Dim iCt As Integer, iUbd As Integer
    
    iCt = LBound(aRy, 1)
    iUbd = UBound(aRy, 1)
    
    Do While iCt < iUbd
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(aRy, 2) To UBound(aRy, 2)
            aRy(iCt, i) = aRy(iCt + 1, i)
        Next i
        iCt = iCt + 1
    Loop

    aRy = transposeArray(aRy)
    ReDim Preserve aRy(1 To UBound(aRy, 1), 1 To UBound(aRy, 2) - 1)
    aRy = transposeArray(aRy)
    
    Shift = aRy

End Function
```

This function uses a custom `transposeArray` function because the built in `Application.Transpose` one is a bit limited and problematic.

```
Function transposeArray(myarr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim myvar As Variant
    ReDim myvar(LBound(myarr, 2) To UBound(myarr, 2), LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1))
    For i = LBound(myarr, 2) To UBound(myarr, 2)
        For j = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)
            myvar(i, j) = myarr(j, i)
        Next
    Next
    transposeArray = myvar
End Function
```

And finally, how we can use it:

```
''Copy the first row of the array to the first row of the table
Tbl.DataBodyRange.Resize(1, UBound(Arr, 2)).Formula = Arr
''use the shift function to essentially remove the first row of the array.
Arr = Shift(Arr)
''copy the remaining rows to the table, starting at it's 2nd row.
Tbl.DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Offset(1).Formula = Arr
```